# How to remove arrows from Django integerField without maintaining the only number input feature?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    registration = forms.IntegerField(label='Registration Number')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','registration','password1', 'password2']
```

How can I remove the up and down arrows from the registration field?
P.S. I want to only allow the user to input numbers in this field.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in CSS:

Like so:

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
```

You should be able to make it specific to that field by using:

```css
#id_registration::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
#id_registration::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding widgets in `Meta` class.

Like this:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
# Import widget that you want
from django.forms import TextInput


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    registration = forms.IntegerField(label='Registration Number')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','registration','password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'registration': TextInput()
        }
```

Also I'm not sure but you can just try this:

```py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    # Add widget to your field
    registration = forms.IntegerField(label='Registration Number', widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','registration','password1', 'password2']
```

For more info:

> [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)